# OSX where does getconf read its value

Tags: osx

I'm not experienced at reverse engineering at all. I hope this basic question is suitable for this site. Basically I want to know where the value `DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR` is read from. I'm trying to trace the system calls like this:

```
sudo bash dtruss /usr/bin/getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR -h -f -a
```

So, it would follow any forked processes too. But, I cannot see any calls that would indicate where it originates from.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I don't know much about OSX, and wouldn't have answered if there had been another answer after 24 hours.

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/getconf.1.html), `getconf` uses `sysconf` and `confstr` to find these configuration values, with [confstr](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/confstr.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/confstr) handling `DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR`. The `confstr` library function might well hard-code these values - if you check the glibc source, you see the glibc version of `confstr` hardcodes `CS_PATH` as well.

However, the `confstr` manual page also states it can return error code `EIO` if there is an "I/O error communicating with opendirectoryd(8)". Which means these values might be opendirectory attributes as well. Check your dtruss output if there are any socket calls; if there aren't, the attributes are probably hard-coded in libc; else, these paths are probably hidden in the opendirectory configuration somewhere.